# Rails 3. How to model people?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I have this Invoicing App.

Currently I have these 4 models:

People:

- Contacts (they're like clients, they will be sent invoices to)
- Users (people that send invoices)
- Company (users belong to company)
- Organization (contacts belongs to organization).

This current setup doesn't really click. It doesn't feel natural.

The other choice I thought about was to create a People model that belongs to Organization.

People, will have a column type_id (types: client, admin, add more in the future)

But I don't know, somehow it feels like the type_id column shouldn't be there to reference just a two row table.

What model setup would you use in this case?

---- **Added for clarification:** ----

Remember that in the near future some clients will have ability to login.
Note: if the client it's just an individual, then he won't belong to an organization.

User represents the person that logs in and sends the invoice. He belongs to a company.

Contact represents the person that is being invoiced, he may or may not belongs to an organization.

[image: models]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) may help in your situation.

Since all that entities are people, you can implement something like this:

[image: Model]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the [single-table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) approach fits multiple user classes if they have differing logic.

But if you have a completely separate Contact and User, and Contacts can't even log in or don't share fields with Users, you should make it a separate model.

Comment: The capability of clients (or people getting the invoices) logging in should be added in the future.

Comment: In a recent project we had a `Partner` model for storing data and a `PartnerUser < User` for logging in.

Answer (score 1):

Your current setup doesn't seem too bad to me.

If the Contacts and Users are going to be substantially different with different data requirements (which my guess is they would), Single Table Inheritance poses more challenges. Think of it like this: if you're going to have a bunch of empty columns depending on whether it's a user or contact, then don't use STI. If very few empty fields, then it could be ok.

How important are the Company and Organization fields? Can the contacts who will be sent invoices just have a text field for company name and address? Maybe that will help simplify things.